# Is there a way for me to get similar css grid behaviour on IE11?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have multiple elements stored in `this.state.recentsArray` being displayed inside Cards in a grid format, with each card never going below 250px and also making it such that the cards are laid out in a way that they will responsively and auto place themselves to make equally wide grid columns regardless of how many elements are in the `recentsArray`. This is achieved with the code below.

react-js:

```
<div className={style.gridLayout}>
  {(this.state.recentsArray).map((element, index) => {
    return (<MyComponent key={index} />
  }
</div>
```

css:

```
.gridLayout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}
```

and the grids are working perfectly fine on all the browsers except for IE, in which each and every single card is always as wide as the screen.

Is there a way for me to replicate the behavior seen in all other browsers for IE using the CSS-grid?

Comment: Try once with IE prefix like: `.gridLayout {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}`

Comment: Auto-fill is not avalaible in ie11. You need to set each children to its position. Grid-row/ grid-column  . Use the prefixed rules. An average alternative could be flex.

Comment: for IE it's best to use a flexbox fallback for such things since it doesn't understand variable grid placements.